# Removing ? from URL after htaccess redirect and rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've made a new site and Googles indexed one of the URLs which Ive since changed so wanted to add a 301 to the new URL. The URLs are SEF URLs so have been rewritten.

Ive managed to create a 301 from the old page to the new with the correct rewritten URL in the browser but the way Ive done it I have a trailing ? at the end of my URL.

Firstly, does this even matter? Will Google rank it as the same page with and without the ? or will it treat the URL with the ? as a separate page of duplicate content?

If its treating it as a separate page then how can I remove this ? at the end?

Here's my rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /search/toys/heroes-of-goo-jit-zu https://example.com/search/figures/heroes-of-goo-jit-zu?
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule .? https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) search.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&subsubcategory=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) search.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) search.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

Without the ? on the end of the rule, I get all the query string on the end of the URL which I don't want. I have tried various flags on the end, both [QSA] and [QSD] cause 500 errors and this is the only method I could find to do the redirect and rewrite without causing 500 errors

Comment: The `[QSA]` is to append the previous query string so remove that if you don't want original query string on URL. Also, `[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]` can be shortened to `[-.\w]`.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean to remove the [qsa] from the lower rewrite rules? I have just tried that and I get the same result.

Comment: Can your provide inbound URL and rewritten URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive will preserve the trailing `?` on the target URL. You should use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive instead to do as you require and remove the query string. And since you are using mod_rewrite for other redirects/rewrites you should avoid mixing redirects from both modules in order to avoid accidental conflicts. (mod_rewrite is always processed first, despite the apparent order of directives in the config file.)

Using mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteRule ^search/toys/heroes-of-goo-jit-zu$ https://example.com/search/figures/heroes-of-goo-jit-zu [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the original query string from the redirect response.

I've included the end-of-string anchor (`$`) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, although strictly speaking it should be omitted to be equivalent to your original `Redirect` directive (which is prefix-matching).

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the earlier 301 will have been cached. (Test first with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid potential caching issues.)

You are also missing the `L` flag on all your other rules - this should be added. At the very least, this prevents unnecessary processing of later rules, but with the `L` flag missing on the canonical redirect, this could result in an erroneous redirect, exposing the rewritten URL.

**UPDATE:** To clarify the discussion in comments regarding the `QSA` flag. This has nothing to do with your immediate issue. You will need the `QSA` flag if you are expecting a query string to be past on the requested URLs (in order to *merge* the query string with that stated in the *substitution* string), otherwise, this flag should be removed.

> I have tried various flags on the end, both [QSA] and [QSD] cause 500 errors

The *flags* parameter is only available to mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives) - this is not valid on mod_alias `Redirect` (and `RedirectMatch`) directive(s).

Comment: Fantastic. This works perfectly. Thank you